# Accessing plist file by main bundle vs Documents directory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

What is the best way to get property list?

1 - From main bundle, i.e.:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes"  ofType:@"plist"];
```

2 - Or get path from Documents directory, i.e.:

```
// Data.plist code - get path from root direcory 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
// get the path to our plist file.
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"]; 
// check to see if Data.plist exists in documents 
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) { 
    // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle 
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]; 
}
```

What and why?
And if both are correct then why do we not use 1st one with just one line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule:

- If the property list file is **read-only** put it in the bundle.
- If the property list file is **going to be mutated** put it in the document directory.

Comment: More importantly, a file in the app bundle is packaged as part of the app. A file in the Documents folder is a runtime event. The file does not start out as part of the app.